# Remove a To do List's item using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm still learning React and I'm trying to use it to remove an item from a "to do list".
Here is the code:

```
import { Item } from '../../types/item';
import { useState } from 'react';


type Props = {
  item: Item
}

export const ListItem = ({ item }: Props) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(item.done);

  return (
    <C.Container done={isChecked}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isChecked}
          onChange={e => setIsChecked(e.target.checked)}
        />

        <button onClick={removeItem}><img src="./remove"/></button>
      <label>{item.name}</label>
    </C.Container>
  );
}
```

This button should call the function removeItem that will... remove the item haha.
Any suggestions?

Comment: the parent component will have to define that logic and pass down the removeItem function unless you are using a more advances state management system like useContext, recoil, or redux

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a functional component with useState hook. Create a  state with initial value to be an empty array. then create a function which on click with update the value  in state, it canbe done using useState hook. Simply enter setTodo(). This will create a new entry in your state. You can use array methods to add the returned value from function which is triggered onclick, too delete an entry, simply use a filter method, you can look more about it on w3school, it provides good examples which are easy to understand by biggeners.